# How is it possible to manage gap of solver cplex in julia?

Tags: julia

we can have manual Gap in CPLEX.

```
IRP=Model(solver=CplexSolver(CPX_PARAM_EPGAP=0.00000001))
```

but if we want to attain 0.02% Gap. is this correct?

```
IRP=Model(solver=CplexSolver(CPX_PARAM_EPGAP=0.02))
```

or this is correct?

```
IRP=Model(solver=CplexSolver(CPX_PARAM_EPGAP=0.0002))
```

Would you please help me that which of those is correct? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the description on [IBM Knowledgecenter for CPLEX](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/EpGap.html), for 0.02% you need to enter `0.0002=0.02*0.01`. Therefore, the second one is correct.

```
IRP=Model(solver=CplexSolver(CPX_PARAM_EPGAP=0.0002))
```

> When the value
>
> `|bestbound-bestinteger|/(1e-10+|bestinteger|)`
>
> falls below the value of this parameter, the mixed integer
>   optimization is stopped.
>
> For example, to instruct CPLEX to stop as soon as it has found a
>   feasible integer solution proved to be within **five percent** of optimal,
>   set the relative MIP gap tolerance to **0.05**.

Comment: Thanks very much. if you don't mind, can I ask another question. How is it possible to manage it for mixed integer programing.?